# How to make an empty implementation class in one static library and instead provide concrete implementation in another static library?

Tags: c++, static-libraries

The title might be confusing to understand and let me clarify here:

I am developing two static libraries A and B using CPP. I want to create a class maybe called **Processor** shared by both libraries, and the class will have a member function called process().

I want to achieve that:

When linking both A and B from an application, calling process will use the concrete implementation defined in B,

```
Processor* object = new Processor();
object->process()//process() will have its non-empty implementation in B
```

but when linking only A, the implementation will be empty (because B is not linked) so that the function will do nothing.

Comment: What about calling them the same thing (`A` or `B`) and link with the implementation you want?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am not sure about what you mean, can you please clarify? Thanks

Comment: I meant what Manuel wrote in his answer.

Comment: I really hope you provide compiled binaries when you release this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TedLyngmo says, you can have both `A` and `B` and link only one of them:

`A`

```
class Process {
public:
    void process() { }
};
```

`B`

```
class Process {
public:
    void process() { // do something }
};
```

and link `A` *or* `B` depending on what you want, empty or not.

If you want to link both, you could put the linker option for `B` before `A`, so the linker sees the symbol in `B` and doesn't search in `A`.

This is asking for trouble, though, as if there are symbols in `A` needed to link, there will be multiple definitions of `Process`. And I guess this may depend on linker implementation.